# Delete files with same name at the end of the file

Tags: shell, scripting, find, wildcards, rm

Delete files with same name at the end of the file

i have a lot of files in my folder and sub directories like

```
ajax_hostel_room_master.php.php          class_hostel_registration.php.php
ajax_hostel_room_master.php.php.php      class_hostel_registration.php.php.php
ajax_hostel_room_shifting.php            class_hostel_room_allocation.php
ajax_hostel_room_shifting.php.php        class_hostel_room_allocation.php.php
ajax_hostel_room_shifting.php.php.php    class_hostel_room_allocation.php.php.php
```

I want to keep the filename.php and delete the other files like filename.php.php

Comment: `rm *.php.php* ` this will delete all files that have more than one php extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`rm -- *.php.php` this will delete all files that have more than one php extension

for all sub directories you need

```
find /scripts/tmp -name "*.php.php" -exec rm {} +
```

`/scripts/tmp` is the directory under which my files and subdirectories existed

Comment: this command helps me remove the files in the directory ...I have those files in Sub directory too.....

Comment: Thanks a lot....I tried this find . -name "*.php.php*" -print0 | xargs -0 rm -rf and it worked

Answer (score 4):

To match repeating extensions, with `zsh`:

```
rm -- *.*.*(e{'[[ $REPLY:t =~ "(\..*)\1$" ]]'})
```

Recursively:

```
rm -- **/*.*.*(e{'[[ $REPLY:t =~ "(\..*)\1$" ]]'})
```

That would match `a.php.php` and `b.x.x` and `c.x.y.x.y` (and `.php.php`).

With `ksh93`:

```
rm -- *@(.*)\1
```

Recursively:

```
set -o globstar
rm -- **/*@(.*)\1
```

With GNU `find`, recursively:

```
find . -regex '.*\(\.[^/]*\)\1' -exec rm {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this at the root of your directory where you want to delete the files:

```
find . -name "*.php.php*" -exec rm '{}' \;
```

Comment: Or, under non-embedded Linux, FreeBSD, OSX or Cygwin: `find . -name "*.php.php" -delete`